# How do I remove old Ubuntu update files from /boot?

Tags: ubuntu, updates

How do I remove old Ubuntu update files from `/boot`? I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have done several updates. Now, when I try to update I get the message, “not enough free disk space.”

There are 5 Zip files in `/boot`, but I can’t delete them. It says “permission denied.”

I tried `sudo apt-get-clean`, and got the message “no command found.” A little help here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing kernel updates via `apt-get` or `aptitude` and want to get rid of old/obsolete installs, correct?

The way I clean out older kernels—after I have rebooted and have the new kernel set in place—is to do the following steps.

First, get the name of the kernel the system is currently running by using `uname` like this:

```
uname -r
```

Make a note of that because that is the name of the current active kernel you *don’t* want to remove. Now knowing that, we need to figure out what the other—extraneous—kernels are:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Depending on how many updates have been installed on your system this could be a long list or a short list but it should have at least one extraneous kernel install in there.

Once you see that list, make note of the extraneous kernels and then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.1-generic
```

Or if you use `aptitude` use this variant of the command:

```
sudo aptitude purge linux-image-x.x.x.1-generic
```

That will purge—meaning removes the files and related configs—from your system connected to `linux-image-x.x.x.1-generic` with `x.x.x.1` just being a placeholder in this example for the full kernel version/ID.

If you have more than one extraneous kernel package you want to purge, just run that command for each one or just set multiple kernels in that command like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.1-generic linux-image-x.x.x.2-generic linux-image-x.x.x.3-generic
```

That will tell the system to purge items connected to extraneous kernels, `linux-image-x.x.x.1-generic`, `linux-image-x.x.x.2-generic` and `linux-image-x.x.x.3-generic` in one shot.

After doing that check `/boot` and the directory should now have freed up space.